# Sublime text 3 with Nodejs Package autocomplete not working properly

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3

I am having problem with Sublime text 3 autocomplete for Nodejs package. When I type in "con" the autocomplete show a list of autocomplete for the JavaScript console object. When I move to console.dir(); and press enter, instead of getting the console.dir();, it only show dir();.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to multiple plugins for js in your sublime text.

Try using sublimecodeintel. It has all the support for js files. Also, make sure to install nodejs language pack in sublime.

Or if you want to a specific answer follow this link:

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/advice-on-autocomplete-plugins/26865/2